# No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined in combination of Web.xml and Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here is my root application context class

```
@Configuration
@Import({WebSecurityConfig.class})
public class ContextConfig {
}
```

My WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
       @Override
       public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
               web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
       }

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
               http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/Hello/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                               .hasRole("USER")
                               .and()
                               .formLogin()
                               .permitAll();
       }

       @Override
       protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
               auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                               .and().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
       }

       @Autowired
       public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
           auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
       }
}
```

My Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>webtest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:com/iis/webtest/config/ContextConfig</param-value>  
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My dispatcher servlet xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.iis.*" annotation-config="true" ></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:resources location="/test/" mapping="/**"/>    
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.iis</groupId>
    <artifactId>webtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>webtest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've tried Xml configuration for security. 
I always get the same error. 
I've searched for solutions but I am still unable to find where am i going wrong.

```
Stacktrace
Aug 08, 2016 5:44:39 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 212 ms
Aug 08, 2016 5:44:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:701)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5510)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 08, 2016 5:44:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

Comment: Can i see your stacktrace...and try by reducing the Spring -security jar version to 3.2.5(I had the same prblm,its fixed by that)

Comment: @PrasannaKumar Please see the stacktrace.

Comment: Yup..try be reducing the spring security jar version

Comment: Same error on changing Spring Security version to 3.2.5

Comment: What error..show first line??

Comment: SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:701)

Comment: Same exception..its not related to jars then.

Comment: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined` can you tell me where is `springSequirtyFilterChain` bean ?

Comment: @AsteriskNinja I have seen no tutorial where that been is actually defined manually. I guess it is supposed to be defined by Spring itself . That's why we have EnableWebSecurity annotation and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class. I might be wrong so if u know where to define it then please point me in the right direction.

Comment: can you post the method or class name with `springSecurityFilterChain` if you have

Comment: @AsteriskNinja Sorry I don't know

Comment: do you have any method or class name with `springSecutiyfilterChain` ?

Comment: @AsteriskNinja That name is actually Filter name provided in Web.xml and I don't have any method or class name with springSecutiyfilterChain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the reason but simply changing context config location from

```
 <param-value>classpath:com/iis/webtest/config/ContextConfig</param-value>
```

to

```
<param-value>com.iis.webtest.config.ContextConfig</param-value>
```

works

Comment: You said previously you tried for xml..in that case also it was not working(because classpath will not come into picture there)??

Comment: Yes I tried that but I kept the XML in the classpath only so classpath was present there.
I kept the xml in a config package itself.
If u now know the reason for the exception then please share.

Comment: Reason is not much..it was trying to find the config file/class...since the given path was incorrect it was unable to find that..so it was giving no bean is defined...

Comment: But My Root application context and Beans gets initialized and everything works fine if i remove filter for Spring Security.

Comment: Ya..it was giving no bean defined for springSecurityChain not for config or beans to load.

Comment: I don't understand . 
My ContextConfig file was read by spring in that I have given annotation to include WebSecurityConfig. So why it was not read ? If location was wrong in the Annotation it should have thrown other error. And how can the location be wrong as I have included reference to class in that annotation.

Comment: ya same question running in my mind(I ll research)..what is the current security jar version now?? 4.1 or 3.2.5

Comment: @PrasannaKumar 4.1 and Let me know Plz.

Comment: ya..if i come to know i ll post here..and try one morething give this classpath:com.iis.webtest.config.ContextConfig

Answer (score 0):

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:com/iis/webtest/config/ContextConfig,
classpath:com/iis/webtest/config/WebSecurityConfig </param-value>  
      </context-param>
```

Use above code in web.xml(Since you need to mention spring security `**WebSecurityConfig**` in web.xml ).

Comment: XML validator is giving error on giving 2 param-value elements inside context-param . Also after removing xsi and xmlns ( for ignoring validation) I am getting the same error.

Comment: Also I have used Import annotation for including WebSecurityConfig

Comment: Remove import for WebSecurityConfig..keep only in web.xml..after that also if u get same error let me know

Comment: I get the same error on removing import WebSecurityConfig

Comment: Check updated answer and also remove contextClass param in web.xml...Spring security will use contextLoaderListener(That you have already mentioned)

Comment: Tried that but that does not work either. Same error.